# Sending Google Map route directions through socket

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application which is using Google Maps v2 API and is finding the route between my location and another location. This app is acting as a client to another application on another Android device. The second device has no GPS connection. When I connect the two devices through socket the server (which is running on the second device) should receive the locations from the client and the route.

Now, my problem is with the route. I download the route on the first application and then I use this AsyncTask there to make the overlays on the map:

```
 /** A class to parse the Google Directions in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(6);
            lineOptions.color(Color.MAGENTA);
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}
```

It works fine on the first application. Then I connect to the other application and send the same String which I have downloaded for the routes. I have implemented the same AsyncTask for parsing the String but the application crashes.

[image: Here's what I get in the LogCat:]

Comment: what is line 115 of your `MainActivity`?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)

Comment: meaning that `result` is null, meaning in turn that `routes = parser.parse(jObject);` throws an exception. Replace `e.printStackTrace();` with `Log.error( "ParserTask", "error", e );` to see the real problem in logcat

Comment: org.JSONException: unterminated array at character 19424 of `routes`

Comment: so you are sending the corrupted JSON text over socket. If you are sure, that the JSON comes valid in your 1st device, check the sending code, perhaps it cuts the text off. Print the JSON-string out to see if it's ok

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that routes variable can be null if exception occures making result null in turn.

Regards,
Prateek